# Matlab array storing through loop

Tags: arrays, matlab, loops, variable-assignment, cell-array

I have a for loop and each value `a{i} b{i} c{i}` is equal each time with a specific number. So I was wondering how can I put all those value in an array through loop. The way that I am using I mean this one `[a{i};b{i};c{i}]` it seems that it doesn't work! If I keep 2 out of three values is working but I want the data from all of the values (`a b c`)

You can see the (pseudo)code below:

```
for i=1:number of cells
   Cell{i}.Tri=[a{i};b{i};c{i}]
end
```

Comment: How does it not work? What is the data `a` `b` and `c`? Since you said without the third value it is working please show us a [MCVE]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This can be done without a for loop by using cellfun combined with the cat function. EDIT: As noted in the comments, `cellfun` is itself a loop.

```
% Create all variables
a{1}=rand(10);
a=repmat(a,10,1);
b=a;
c=a; 
% Add a cell array of equal size to a. The contents of each cell are the dimension along which to concatenate. 
catarg=num2cell(ones(size(a)))

% Do the concatenation
d=cellfun(@cat,catarg,a,b,c,'UniformOutput',false);
```

Comment: `cellfun` is a loop.

Answer (score 1):

`cell2mat` is what you need:

```
a = num2cell(rand(1,10));
b = num2cell(rand(1,10));
c = num2cell(rand(1,10));
abc = cell2mat([a;b;c]);
```